# send variable to controller with link_to method rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I have a problem with link_to to send variable. With form_for and submit button works fine, but I need send the data with link_to.

This works fine with form_for:

```
<%= form_for (@post), :method => :post,  :remote => true, :html => { :id => "#{@post.id}" }, :url => { :controller => "posts", :action => "follow", :post_id => post.id } do |f|  %> 
<%= f.submit "Follow" %>
<% end %>
```

This not works :(:

```
<%= link_to post_path(@post), :method => :post, :remote => true, :html => { :id => "#{@post.id}" }, :url => { :controller => "posts", :action => "follow", :post_id => post.id }  do%> 
<em></em>
<%= "Follow" %>
<% end %>
```

This last, link_to not send params, and my controller not receive the params and get a error type **InvalidFind (Calling Document#find with nil is invalid):**

### Edited:

**I found now a solution...the params must be set into the target-
parameter:**

```
<%= link_to post_path(:post_id => post.id), :method => :post, :remote => true, :html => { :id => "#{@post.id}" }, :url => { :controller => "posts", :action => "follow" }  do%>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You send params with any url/path helpers. Just pass in hash key/value pairs like this.

```
<%= link_to post_path(@post, :my_param => "param value"), .... %>
```

Comment: I see that you found the answer yourself too. Would you mind accepting  my answer if it's correct? Thanks.