# What is causing this undefined method `model_name' for Hash:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

I am trying to implement a link in rails that will point to a certain url with a delete: method and with some params in the url, what I am trying is this:

```
<%= link_to "Remove", [:remove_country, :admin, @species, my_param: country.id ], method: :delete %>
```

Note the my_param: country.id I am trying to pass in. This gives me the result:

```
undefined method `model_name' for Hash:Class
```

due to the hash in the params. Unfortunately I need that there as I am trying to pass an extra param into the url (my_param which is country.id in this example)

as far as I can remember this is the correct method to pass params into a link_to in rails. The normal link_to that I use (without the my_param) is below, that works perfectly:

```
<%= link_to "Remove from this species", url_for([:remove_country, :admin, @species]), method: :delete %>
```

So how do I incorporate my param into this url? thanks in advance. ([here is a source for why I think this should work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232393/send-variable-to-controller-with-link-to-method-rails-3))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `polymorphic_path([:remove_country, :admin, @species], {country_id: country.id})`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made a hacky solution but I don't like it one bit:

```
<%= link_to "Remove", url_for([:remove_country, :admin, @species]) + "?country_id=#{country.id}", method: :delete %>
```

It's very ugly, please someone put me out of my misery and show me a nice way to do this.

Comment: Why do not you just see this and follow http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Comment: Follow what? there doesn't appear to be a single solution in there that works in this case (where we need a polymorphic path).