# How to dynamically transmit params in link_to ?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, refactoring

I need to use part of my application in iframe on another page. So I need to remove layout on these pages.

I added to **ApplicationController**

```
layout :current_layout
def current_layout
  if params[:layout] == false.to_s
    false
  else
    'main'
  end
end
```

This works until user click on any link in navigation. So I need to add to every link_to in this part of application something like:

```
link_to 'store', store_path(params.merge({layout: params[:layout]})
```

I am wondering that maybe I can refactor that and maybe remove this `params.merge` from every link?

Comment: You need ALL your params in your link?

Comment: @regedarek is there any reason you would not want to write a helper function to do this?

Comment: @MikeH-R how this helper could looks like?

Comment: @regedarek was that any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
def my_path_helper(string, path_type, params)
  link_to(string, polymorphic_path([path_type], params.merge({layout: params[:layout]})))
end
```

See [the docs for polymorphic path here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) and also this [answer that provides an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778027/what-is-causing-this-undefined-method-model-name-for-hashclass).

Is this what you were looking for?